# Redirecting and rendering a notice with format.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have come across an a scenario where I'm not sure if things could be handled better.

When using remotipart to upload files through an ajax call, all actions are carried out by js

```
Processing by DocumentsController#create as JS
```

I couldn't get the page to redirect using a js response, but then I found a solution on here

```
if @document.save
     format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: success_save_msg }
     format.js { render :js => "window.location.href='"+root_path+"'" }
   else
     format.html
     format.js { render action: 'create.js.erb' }
   end
```

So the page does redirect but i no longer get a notice like I do if I was rendering html.

Is there a better way to handle this or a way to show the notice with my current implementation

### Update

I have done this so far (in essence the same thing I know, but thought a little cleaner as redirect path not hard-coded in the controller)

```
if @document.save
 format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: success_save_msg }
 format.js { render action: 'redirect.js.erb }
else
 format.html
 format.js { render action: 'create.js.erb' }
end
```

redirect.js.erb

```
window.location.replace("<%= root_path %>");
```

Though this still doesn't feel right.

### Update 2

I have pieced this together, though please feel free to add cleaner solutions, I would really like to know how to handle this in the most efficient and correct way.

```
def create
@document = current_user.documents.new(document_params)
respond_to do |format|

   if @document.save
     format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: success_save_msg }
     format.js { flash[:notice] = 'File Successfully Uploaded'
                 render action: 'redirect.js.erb'
               }
   else
     format.html
     format.js { render action: 'create.js.erb' }
   end

end
```